# Is it possible to stack datasets with different variables in SAS?

Tags: sas

Say I have 2 datasets

```
dataset1 = 
          123456789
          222222222
          444444444

dataset2 = 
          123456  8888   account1_description
          456789  7777   account2_description
```

I'm trying to get a similar output as the following example 
stacking the 2 datasets and having a string as indicators between

```
[HEADER_2015-01-01]          <----inserted as a line of characters (string)
[ID]                         <----inserted as a line of characters (string)
123456789
222222222
444444444
[ACCOUNT]                    <----inserted as a line of characters (string)
123456     8888   account1_description
456789     7777   account2_description
[DETAIL]                     <----inserted as a line of characters (string)
```

my initial thought to achieve this is by creating different datasets, then append/stack them together. 
for example: 
dataset1(char) = [HEADER_2015-01-01] 
dataset2(char) = [ID] 
dataset3(number) = 
  123456789 
    222222222 
   444444444
dataset4(char) = [ACCOUNT] 
dataset5 = ...
etc.

but obviously that's wrong because the first column (variable) is having different data formats. Can someone suggest a way to achieve this kind of output? thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to see what you're trying to get at given the format of your data above. Can you reformat the data to make it more clear?

Comment: Hi Reeza, what I'm trying to get is really simple, just to stack multiple datasets together without changing their formats, and insert a char header between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS datasets are roughly analagous to SQL tables.  They are not excel files.  As such, it is not possible to do exactly what you're asking (have different variables on different rows).

You could have each row simply be one text string, in which case that can have whatever value you want.  Or you can have different variables, stack them, and be okay that the different columns aren't aligned; it will stack fine, it just won't align the misaligned columns.

You could use SQL to UNION them and force the columns to stack, but they'd have to be the same data type.

In any event, this is not something you *should* do in SAS, regardless.  The right way is to turn your headers into variables that have the same value for every row that should be under that header, then you could `proc report` it back out with a similar structure.